# Results about Jacobson radicals

Tags: ring-theory, modules

[image]

c)[image]

How can I mimick that proof?

Answer (score 2):

It virtually writes itself!

Suppose $M$ is nonzero and let $S=\{M'\subseteq M\mid IM'\neq\{0\}\}$. Let $N$ be a minimal element.

Since $IN\neq\{0\}$, there exists an $x\in N$ such that $Ix\neq\{0\}$. By minimality of $N$, $Rx=N$ and thus $N$ is finitely generated.

We want to show that $IN=\{0\}$ to finish. This is obvious since $IN\in S$ (because $I(IN)=IN\neq \{0\}$) and $IN\subseteq N$, so minimality of $N$ says again that $N=IN$. By Nakayama's lemma, $N=\{0\}$.

That is a contradiction, so our hypothesis that $M\neq\{0\}$ was mistaken.

---

As for how it helps prove the nilpotency of $J(R)$, suppose that the powers of $J(R) $ are all nonzero.  This is a decreasing sequence which must stabilize at some point, say at $n$.  Then $J(R)^n$ is idempotent and Artinian, so it is zero, a contradiction .

Comment: We want to show... You meant $IN=N$ right?

Comment: Could you please help me on part d?

Comment: I want to use part c like it says otherwise I have: $M$ simple $R$-module. Then $IM=M$ or $IM=0$, but $IM=M$ is not possible since $0=I^nM=I^{n-1}M=\ldots=M$ contradicting $M$ simple. So $IM=0$ so $I \subset Ann(M)$ so $I \subset J(R)$

Comment: Could you please confirm the above

Comment: @Walter Yes, $J(R)$ contains all nilipotent ideals of $R$.

Comment: I don't understand how I'm using part c) though.

Comment: @Walter I added to the answer but I'm not totally sure what other things you have at your disposal. Do you know why ideals of an Artinian ring are Artinian modules?

Comment: Don't think so. What theorem is that (does it have a name? or some sort of reference so I can double check)

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence in your post (idempotent and ...) I haven't covered that

Comment: @Walter It's not a famous Theorem. Just an elementary fact that submodule son of Artinian modules are also Artinian.  All I did was apply c) to $I=J(R)^n=M$.